# Решение формулы, представленной в виде строки

Tags: python, алгоритм

У меня есть строка типа a = '2(asd)'. Нужно получить вывод asdasd. Подскажите, как это реализовать с использованием стронних библиотек и без них. Также есть пример строки '2(as)3(4(vcx)' в этом примере блоки '2(as)' и '3(4(vcx) нужно сложить, подскажите кто знает

Comment: Распишите преобразование на бумаге и реализуйте с использование рекурсии или стека.

Comment: А чему равно 3(4(vcx)? И скобка не закрыта специально или это опечатка?